# I can't read all the data table, it returns to me only the first row correct

Tags: php, laravel

I want to return a list of appointments for a given user (Appointment table contains `user_id` and `post_id`).

The problem is, the returned collection only got the name and place for the first appointment.

```
public function index()
{
    // Retrieve all appointments from the user
    $appointments = Appointment::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();

    // Retrieve all post IDs associated with the appointments
    $postIds = $appointments->pluck('post_id')->toArray();

    // Retrieve all posts with the associated post IDs
    $posts = Post::whereIn('id', $postIds)->get()->keyBy('id');

    // Assign post details to each appointment
    $appointments = $appointments->map(function ($appointment) use ($posts) {
        $postId = $appointment->post_id;

        if (isset($posts[$postId])) {
            $post = $posts[$postId];
            $appointment->name = $post->name;
            $appointment->place = $post->place;
        } else {
            // For debugging purposes, log the missing post details
            Log::info("Post details not found for appointment: " . $appointment->id);
        }
        return $appointment;

    });

    return $appointments;

}
```

And the result I got in postman is below:

```
[
    {
        "id": 4,
        "user_id": 9,
        "post_id": 2,
        "date": "6/14/2023",
        "day": "Wednesday",
        "time": "12:00 PM",
        "status": "upcoming",
        "created_at": "2023-06-12T17:19:58.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2023-06-12T17:19:58.000000Z",
        "name": "Biskra",
        "place": "Tolga"
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "user_id": 9,
        "post_id": 9,
        "date": "6/24/2023",
        "day": "Saturday",
        "time": "14:00 PM",
        "status": "cancel",
        "created_at": "2023-06-12T18:53:45.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2023-06-12T18:53:45.000000Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "user_id": 9,
        "post_id": 8,
        "date": "6/17/2023",
        "day": "Saturday",
        "time": "12:00 PM",
        "status": "complete",
        "created_at": "2023-06-13T01:43:14.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2023-06-13T01:43:14.000000Z"
    }
]
```

I want to get the list of appointments of user with the information of each appointment (date, time, day, post_name, post_place)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the attempt to modify original appointments to get the results, Please check your code

```
    // Assign post details to each appointment
    
    $appointments = $appointments->map(function ($appointment) use ($posts) {
    }
```

The results has to be placed in different variable to get the correct result out

```
// Assign post details to each appointment
$allTheRecords = $appointments->map(function ($appointment) use ($posts) {
    $postId = $appointment->post_id;

    if (isset($posts[$postId])) {
        $post = $posts[$postId];
        $appointment->name = $post->name;
        $appointment->place = $post->place;
    } else {
        // For debugging purposes, log the missing post details
        Log::info("Post details not found for appointment: " . $appointment->id);
    }

    return $appointment;
});

return $allTheRecords;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Eloquent: API Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-resources) if you are building an API to transform the data as you need.

Change your index function to eager load `post` with appointments and return a
resource collection.

```
public function index()
{
    // Retrieve all appointments for the user with posts
    $appointments = Appointment::with('post')->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();
    return AppointmentResource::collection($appointments);
}
```

If your Appoinment model does not already have a `post` relation, add it.

```
public function post()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
}
```

Create a new resource using below command

```
php artisan make:resource AppointmentResource
```

In your `App\Http\Resources\AppointmentResource`;

```
public function toArray(Request $request): array
{
    return [
        "id": $this->id,
        "user_id": $this->user_id,
        "post_id": $this->post_id,
        "date": $this->date,
        "day": $this->day,
        "time": $this->time,
        "status": $this->status,
        "created_at": $this->created_at,
        "updated_at": $this->updated_at,
        "name": $this->post->name,
        "place": $this->post->place
    ];
}
```

If you don't need to transform data and just need to access the data you can just access `post` relation when you are iterating in the view like `$appoinment->post->name`.

```
@foreach ($appointments as $appointment)
    {{ $appointment->post->name }}
@endforeach
```